# jquery-emoji-picker use multi textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, emoji

i have multi textarea i would put emoji for any textarea have same id or class
it`s not work with me and come for first one

http://codepen.io/hesham-farag/pen/PWGNxB

```
    <textarea class="inputMessage " id="input-default" placeholder="emoji add" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

  <textarea class="inputMessage " id="input-default" placeholder="emoji add" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

trigger js

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('#input-default').emojiPicker();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another emoji picker which can solve your problem. Just include js file and follow the settings.
See github page - [Emoji picker](https://github.com/woody180/vanilla-javascript-emoji-picker)

```
new FgEmojiPicker({
   trigger: ['button', 'textarea'],
   position: ['bottom', 'right'],
   emit(obj, triggerElement) {
       const emoji = obj.emoji;
       document.querySelector('textarea').value += emoji;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//use seperate Ids
<textarea class="inputMessage " id="input-default1" placeholder="emoji add" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

   <textarea class="inputMessage " id="input-default2" placeholder="emoji add" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </form> 


   $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('#input-default1,#input-default2').emojiPicker();
});
```

Comment: put this will be post like facebook post

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to say?

Comment: i have a many  div will take same class .  it will be like comment on facebook , so i couldn`t change name ID